# D3.js Looking for efficient way to hide selective hierarchical elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a sunburst diagram that I want to show all elements (ascendants and descendants) related to a selected element. I want the proportions of the non-filtered elements to stay the same (basically opacity set to 0).

As an example if I wanted to only show *apple* elements the crossed out elements would disappear, but apple and all it's (ascendants and descendants) will still be there.

[image: sunburst showing removed elements]

Here's a MWE that outputs the sunburst (unfiltered) https://jsfiddle.net/pcristini/d7ot253c/70/. I'm not sure how to approach this other than the `arcVisible` function I have defined, I just don't know the best way to go about it.

Also, any feedback related to how I did anything else in the code would be appreciated. I haven't done much with D3 previously and my JS skills are far from strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have no idea if this is a super efficient method but this is what I came up with.

So first off I start by finding the max at the level specified

```
function findMax(data, level) {
  var max;
  var orgs = {};
  
  // Loop over each data element
  data.each(d => {
    // if it's at the specified depth
    if (d.depth == level)
    {
      // If it's not already in the orgs structure (counting the maxs), add it
      if (!(d.data.name in orgs))
      {
        orgs[d.data.name] = 0;
      }
      // Increase the total of this value
      orgs[d.data.name] += d.value;
    }
  });
  // Find the element with the maximum value
  max = Object.entries(orgs).reduce((a, e) => e[1] > a[1] ? e : a);

  // Just return the name
  return max[0];
}
```

Now we can find all the ancestors and descendants of the selected max

```
function maxTrees(data, name){
  var max_el = [];
  
  data.each(d => {
    if (d.data.name == name)
      // Put all the ancestors and descendants into an array
      max_el = max_el.concat(d.ancestors().reverse().slice(1), d.descendants().slice(1));
  });
  
  return max_el;  
}
```

Now when we show the visible elements we lookup whether the current slice is part of the visible list:

```
function arcVisible(d) {
  return max_elements.indexOf(d) >= 0;
}


path.attr("fill-opacity", d => arcVisible(d) ? 0.6 : 0.0);
```

I have updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcristini/d7ot253c/73/) with the solution. I was actually looking for the max count (unlike what I asked in the MWE above... my apologies)